# How to authorize but penalize delays in production planning?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am coding an Or-tools CP-SAT system to optimize a production schedule based on NewIntervalVar. The system contains a large number of constraints, including the customer orders with: product, quantity and expected delivery date.

Here, for example, is the order book in dictionary by product (product number):

```
order_per_product = {
0:[[25,0],[75,2],[15,3]],  #NrProduct0:[[Quantity,DayExpectedDelivery],[order2..],
1:[[112,0],[240,5]],       #Nrproduct1:...
2:[[785,4]],
3:[[25,1],[425,3],[78,4]],
4:[[155,3],[78,6],[45,7]] 
}
```

Since I don't want to prohibit production/delivery delays, but rather limit/impact them, my idea is to maximize schedule profitability by impacting sales prices on delays. By setting several selling prices according to the level of delay, for example:

```
sales_price = {
0:12, #no delay -> price 12€
1,11,#1 day delay -> price 11€
2:9,
3:7,
4:5}
```

Or-tools must therefore first compare the planning list with the order list to find out what the possible delivery delays are.
My planning list could look like this, 50 production runs fixed with OR-tools variables and stored in a list:

```
 for i in range (50):
   NrProduct = new(0,4, 'NrProduct')
   quantity = new(1,55, 'quantity')
   day = new(0,30, 'day')
   production_schedle.append([Nrproduct, quantity, day])
```

Let's take a small example, If OR-tools decides to produce NrProduct "0" in two series on day 1 and day 3 respectively, the schedule would look like this:

`production_schedle = [[0,45,1], [0,150,3]]` #or-tools variables

So knowing the order book on product "0": `0:[[25,0],[75,2],[15,3]]`, OR-tools should return:

```
delay_list=[[
[25,1], #[Quantity, late/early], here 1 day late
[20,-1], #here 1 day early
[55,1],
[15,0]],
[80]] 80 #remaining quantity,(we could also set a different price for for surplus quantities, will be allocated to stock).
```

Would you have another idea for integrating delays, perhaps there are already functions that can handle this with another approach?

If not, how would you go about getting OR-tool to return delays using the approach I presented in the example above?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is quite possible to implement this with CP-SAT:

for a given order, its due date id `d`.
You will create an integer variable that describes the delivery date: `delivery`.

The domain of `delivery` with be `[0, d + 4]`.

The delay will be another variable with a domain of `[0, 4]`.

You link the delay and the delivery with a max equality constraint.

```
model.AddMaxEquality(delay, [0, delivery - d])
```

Now you need a `price` variable.

```
price = model.NewIntVarFromDomain(cp_model.Domain.FromValues([5, 7, 9, 11, 12])
```

You need to link the `price` with the `delay`:

```
model.AddElement(delay, [12, 11, 9, 7, 5], price)
```

the final reporting is standard python, so I leave it to you.

PS: Note that the element constraint will be expanded to a set of enforced linear equations. See [this more general encoding of step functions](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/integer_arithmetic.md#python-code-2).

Comment: Thanks Laurent,
That mostly unblocks me,
The only small difficulty I have left is to link the `delivery` var to my `production_schedle = production_schedle.append([Nrproduct, quantity, day])` 
Knowing that a production run can be only part of an order, or on the contrary be a complete order plus part of a second order. 
So an order can be honored in several runs therefore possibly with several days of production

Comment: Usually the delivery date is the end expression of the final interval variable.